# manga with guns but transported to another world

Tags: story-identification, manga

I'm looking for a manga I lost. It's about a guy playing in a VR world with guns.

He has white hair, he falls off the map and wakes up in fantasy world inside his character's body. He kills monsters for points to buy ammo and uses sci-fi gear to explore dungeons.

Everyone in town calls him some name meaning "no magic". When no one is looking he can use a power suit with helmet.

Answer (score 4):

"Manuke na FPS Player ga Isekai e Ochita Baai" a/k/a "When a Stupid FPS Player Falls to Another World"

Description: The protagonist is a player of a VRMMOFPS game who ends up falling off the map while playing in PvE mode, and ends up being transported to a fantasy world with his FPS system.

Author: Jiraigen
Artist: Saiki Junichi

Comment: Cheers been looking for days thanks.

Comment: @BrandonCadenaro You can mark this answer as correct by "accepting" it (click the checkmark on the left, below the voting buttons).